# Node Media Help

Tags: 7, media, files

I want to add media to my node. I have installed Media 2.x, Media Multiselect and Plupload modules and I can upload multiple items to but unfortunatley I cannot insert multiple items to my File field. I select multiple items in Media Library and click submit but only one of them gets inserted.

Is there a way to insert multiple items from Media Library to File field?